# Matrix Generator,Coding Theory

Tags: coding-theory

I have code $C$ with given codewords $C=\{110,011,101,000\}$ I have to generate a matrix for $C$ and words has to be written with length 4.

Im using $G=I|(n-k)$ where $n = 3$ and $k =2$ but word is only 3 and needed to be with length of 4.Im confused I need help to clarificate idea of matrix generator for codes.

Comment: The length of your code $C$ is most certainly $n=3$. There are various and sundry ways of extending it to length $n=4$, but it would no longer be the same code. Something has to give.